# DataReader does not read my if code

Tags: c#, datareader

I have a login winform and i put Change Password in it. I have this code for updating my password info in my database. But it does not read my datareader if it is in true, but if it is in false it will read it, and change the password in my database.

```
    public void ChangePass()
    {
        sc.Open();
        try
        {
            if (_oldpass == "" || _newpass == "" || _conpass == "")
            {
                string message = "Must fill up all the fields!";
                string title = "Voting System Error Message";
                MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT password FROM TableLogin WHERE password = '" + _oldpass + "'", sc);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read() == true)
                {
                    sc.Close();
                    if (_newpass == _conpass)
                    {
                        sc.Open();
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TableLogin SET password = '" + _newpass + "' WHERE username = 'admin'", sc);

                        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        if (sdr.Read() == true) 
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Changed!"); 
//This part does not read if true.. but if sdr.Read() == false it changes the password from my database.
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string message = "New Password and Confirm Password does not match!";
                        string title = "Voting System Error Message";

                        MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    string message = "Wrong Old Password!";
                    string title = "Voting System Error Message";

                    MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

I don't understand, why?

Comment: Your code is ***ripe*** for SQL injection.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) would love that code

Comment: You're executing a "read" on a non-scalar query. I would not expect this to work as you have it coded.

Comment: A: SQL injection, and B: ***stop storing passwords***.

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner in programming. @Joel, I just want to ask if how do i do it base on my codes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `Update` statement in sql will not return records so read will not return `true`. You should use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead.

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Changed!"); 
}
```

BTW as pointed in comments use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

The following is CW, as it's really a big comment. There are many changes I'd make to your code. Here are some of the important ones:

```
    public void ChangePass()
    {
        // Not very important, but this doesn't need to be in the try/catch
        if (_oldpass == "" || _newpass == "" || _conpass == "")
        {
            var message = "Must fill up all the fields!";
            var title = "Voting System Error Message";
            MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            // SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, and anything else you create that implements
            // IDisposable, needs to be in a using block
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT password FROM TableLogin WHERE password = @Password", sc))
            {
                // As others have said, use parameters to avoid SQL Injection Attacks
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", _oldpass);

                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read()) // You don't need == true
                    {
                        if (_newpass == _conpass)
                        {
                            // Separate SqlCommand and use a using block
                            using (
                                var updateCommand =
                                    new SqlCommand(
                                        "UPDATE TableLogin SET password = @Password WHERE username = 'admin'",
                                        sc))
                            {
                                // and a parameter
                                updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", _newpass);

                                // Use ExecuteNonQuery, and check affected rows
                                var rowsAffected = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                if (rowsAffected == 1)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Changed!");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var message = "New Password and Confirm Password does not match!";
                            var title = "Voting System Error Message";

                            MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var message = "Wrong Old Password!";
                        var title = "Voting System Error Message";

                        MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // For troubleshooting purposes, display the entire exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```